# jQuery UI: Multiple vertical sliders to be aligned on a same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been struggling to get multiple vertical UI sliders on a same line.
What i want is as follows:
1. Multiple vertical UI sliders on a same line. Say I want 4 vertical sliders put one after another in a row.
2. I wish to display the numbers when the user shifts each slider

The code that i have been following gives me the numbers on each slider.
However, currently the sliders are one below another (in a same column)... How can I bring them into a row format

I was trying to share my code via fiddle, but was experiencing difficulties.

I will really appreciate if someone can help me fix this.

MY HTML + JS CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Slider functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#slider-4" ).slider({
               orientation:"vertical" 
            });
            $( "#slider-4" ).slider({
               orientation:"vertical",
               value:50,
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#minval4" ).val( ui.value );
               }  
            });
            $( "#minval4" ).val( $( "#slider-4" ).slider( "value" ) );
            $( "#slider-5" ).slider({
               orientation:"vertical",
               value:50,
               slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#minval5" ).val( ui.value );
               }  
            });
            $( "#minval5" ).val( $( "#slider-5" ).slider( "value" ) );
         });
      </script>
      <!-- Pasted your code here -->
      <style>
        [id^="slider-"] + p {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 1em;
          }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
         <div class="container">
         <div id="slider-4"></div>
         <p>
            <label for="minval4">Minumum value4:</label>
            <input type="text" id="minval4" 
               style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
         </p>
         <div id="slider-5"></div>
         <p>
            <label for="minval5">Minumum value5:</label>
            <input type="text" id="minval5" 
               style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
         </p>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I moved each slider and `<p>` into a its own section:

```
  <div class="container">
     <section class="slider">
        <div id="slider-4"></div>
        <p>
           <label for="minval4">Minumum value4:</label>
           <input type="text" id="minval4" 
              style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
        </p>            
     </section>
     <section class="slider">
        <div id="slider-5"></div>
        <p>
           <label for="minval5">Minumum value5:</label>
           <input type="text" id="minval5" 
              style="border:0; color:#b9cd6d; font-weight:bold;">
        </p>            
     </section>
   </div>
```

Then, I added this, just before the close of `</head>`:

```
  <style>
    section.slider {
     float: left;
    }
  </style>
```

**Code**: https://gist.github.com/antibland/6c43a6f20d5fce3a3bc8ad7324731516

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply... I tried the procedure you suggested. However, now I am not getting the vertical sliders anymore. The labels minimum value:4 and 5 are on same line now.... Can you suggest a way to bring the vertical sliders on the same line too

Comment: What i can realise is... that the style that you shared with me is conflicting with another UI style <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">..... Which is embedded in the HTML script

Comment: I adjusted my answer. It says to target paragraph tags immediately following divs starting with the id equal to "slider-".

Comment: You could also put a class on on the paragraph tags and target them directly.

Comment: Hi Andy... Thank you so much for the information. I pasted the code you shared at the location where you asked me to (see the modified code)... But the code is getting displayed on the web page instead of changing the alignment of the sliders... I tried giving the cod in the <style> block, but that also didn't work. I might be asking too much, but can you please share the right code with me...

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried it once again (putting the code within <style></style>))... But that didn't work for me... Please see the updated code above... Sorry for asking dumb questions... I really appreciate your kind help :)

Comment: Move that block of code so that it's inside head, right before the closing tag.

Comment: Hi Andy... I tried that approach as well... It doesn't seem to run... I am still getting the sliders one below another.. Am i also supposed to write something where you put a tag 'enter code here'?? ... Please see the modified code... Thanks

Comment: Thanks Andy. Upon running your code, i can see the following deviations: 1. I can't see any sliders in the output window. There is just an empty box.. 2. The labels like Minimum value:4 and 5 are on the same line now.... I wanted the vertical sliders to be on the same line too.. Are you able to see vertical sliders grouped horizontally at your end? I really don't have any clue... Can you please let me know if i am missing something? Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your external resources are http and not https. jsFiddle is blocking them from loading, which is why your sliders aren't showing up. You'll have to create a demo some other way and provide a link.

Comment: Hi Andy. If jsfiddle is giving trouble, can you let me know why the code isn't working while i am writing my scripts normally via a text editor... Also can quickly explain when you say "You'll have to create a demo some other way and provide a link"... Thanks :)

Comment: Any luck with the latest answer?